# R: Make a array baseplot and color by array dim levels

Tags: r, arrays, plot, colors

Hi I want to know how to color a baseplot of array data for different array levels (dimnames 1, 2 and 3)

```
x <- rnorm(1000); dim(x) <- c(10,10,10)

dimnames(x) = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"),
                   c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"),
                   c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"))
```

```
plot(x, col=as.factor(dimnames(x)[[3]]))
```

didn't give me the wanted results as...

```
plot(x[1:100], col=as.factor(dimnames(x)[[3]]))
```

didn't give me one color for the first 100 numbers

I want to know how I can color the base plot by the different sets over the dimensions in baseplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get back the array index, i.e which sub-array the datapoint belongs to and provide something as long as your data points to plot, for example:

```
plotfunc = function(this_array,index_to_plot){
array_index = 1+(index_to_plot - 1) %/% prod(dim(this_array)[1:2])
COLS=as.factor(dimnames(this_array)[[3]])[array_index]
plot(this_array[index_to_plot],col=COLS)
}
```

If you are plotting 1:100 from array x your provided, you are plotting the first sub-array, and all's black:

```
plotfunc(x,1:100)
```

[image]

We can try from the first 50 from the first 3 sub-arrays:

```
plotfunc(x,c(1:50,101:150,201:250))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me why you put the 1+(......-1) functionality in there?

Is it correct that the [array_index] after as.factor..... asks for a set of the factor lvls just like you take other subsets but for factors it will take the length of the request

Comment: Ok yes, so your array is (10x10) repeated 10 times. in the array, it is flattened out. what you want is a function that tells you which of the (10x10) it belongs to, so a function where numbers 1-100 gives 1, 101-200 give 2 and so on.. I used the %% , and you can see, 1 %% 100 gives 0, and 999 %% 100 gives 9.. it works better to move this by 1, hence the +1

Comment: Got it why you use that functionality. Thanks

Comment: To plot, you need to provide a factor variable that is as long as your x and y variable. So yes, it calls out a vector of dimension names that corresponding to the index, i.e 1 will be A, 101 will be B and so on, and converts this to factors to be plotted

Comment: Pls wait with an answer, let me try to get a formula of myself to get 1:10 gives 1 etc. But 201:210 gives 1 again.

Comment: for quick plotting I tend to use baseplot. I came upon the array and wanted to plot and distinguish between the different lvls (all the data, first level down and second level down) in the array. But I figured there was no such straight forward way of doing that. So I tried to figure out how to.

Comment: Ok cool. I guess you were trying to plot the different levels. Hope it's of some help to you. ps: very weird someone downvoted you..

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what I wanted, at least with a 10x10x10 array, I have to validate it for different array dimensions. Also make it more strict by making sure only 1,2 or 3 can be choosen for array_level.

```
plotfunc2 = function(this_array,index_to_plot,array_level)
if (array_level == 1){
  plot(this_array[index_to_plot])
} else if (array_level == 2){
  array_index = 1+(index_to_plot - 1) %/% prod(dim(this_array)[1:2])
  COLS=as.factor(dimnames(this_array)[[3]])[array_index]
  plot(this_array[index_to_plot],col=COLS)
} else if (array_level == 3){
  array_index = rep(rep(c(1:dim(this_array)[3]), each = dim(this_array)[3]), times = dim(this_array)[3])
  COLS=as.factor(dimnames(this_array)[[2]])[array_index]
  plot(this_array[index_to_plot],col=COLS)
}
```

plotfunc2(x,1:500,3) gives

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the input

I tried to adjust the function in order to select the level of the array I want the colors to be taken over. But I can't seem to get the lowest level right since it takes only the factor levels over 1:10 and if I go on the lowest array level (sets of 10) I can't figure out to get the formula right.

```
plotfunc2 = function(this_array,index_to_plot,array_level)
if (array_level == 1){
  plot(this_array[index_to_plot])
} else if (array_level == 2){
  array_index = 1+(index_to_plot - 1) %/% prod(dim(this_array)[1:2])
  COLS=as.factor(dimnames(this_array)[[3]])[array_index]
  plot(this_array[index_to_plot],col=COLS)
} else if (array_level == 3){
  array_index = 1+(index_to_plot - 1) %/% dim(this_array)[3]
  COLS=as.factor(dimnames(this_array)[[2]])[array_index]
  plot(this_array[index_to_plot],col=COLS)
}
```

[image]